# Is there a window opacity command in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, opacity

I've been searching a lot but I can't find anything useful, the only answers I found were on how to change the opacity of an image using a .bat file. I just found out recently that you could change the opacity of the CMD window under properties, I want to know if you can do the same in a batch file using just a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait for [windows 10](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/09/windows-10-command-prompt-finally-gets-dragged-into-the-21st-century/).

Meanwhile you can [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).It's an enhanced console for powershell and cmd.exe. And some other [alternatives](http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-better-windows-console-tools-alternatives-to-windows-built-in-command-prompt/).

[From the development team](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/) and [a place to comment - sort-of](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/category/87959-feedback)

Comment: You provided more info.

Comment: Ahhh well Windows 10 has been out for some time now, is there a way to do this now?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIAA, ot until Windows 10...